# Symfony 3.4 upgrade has broken PHPUnit test around PreAuthenticationToken SSO testing

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, symfony-3.4, php-7.2

I am upgrading my Symfony 2.8 app to 3.4 and I am hitting some issues with an existing PHPUnit test.

This is my `security.yml`:

```
security:
   firewalls:
        default:
            simple_preauth:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                authenticator: appbundle.admin.tokenauthenticator
```

I have recently upgraded the `friendsofsymfony/user-bundle` to `v2.1.2` as part of this Symfony 3.4 upgrade.

`config_test.yml` (for PHPUnit):

```
security:
    providers:
        appbundle.security.api.key_user_provider:
            apiusers:
                users:
                    server:
                        apikey: testUserValidRole
                        roles:
                            - 'ROLE_API_USER'
```

I have also upgrade PHP to 7.2 and PHPUnit to 7.4.3.

In my test I have this:

```
$crawler = $client->request('POST', '/api/sso', [
    'apikey' => 'testUserValidRole',
    'site' => $site->getId(),
]);

$this->assertEquals(
     \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response::HTTP_OK,
     $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode()
);

$response = json_decode($client->getResponse()->getContent());
$this->assertTrue(isset($response->target));

$security = $client->getProfile()->getCollector('security');

// The user should only be authenticated anonymously.
$this->assertTrue($security->isAuthenticated());
$this->assertEquals(
     'Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\AnonymousToken',
     $security->getTokenClass()
);

// Check that we can login with a valid loginToken.
// Note: A successful login will redirect and remove the loginToken.
$client->enableProfiler();
$crawler = $client->request('GET', $response->target);

// The user should be authenticated correctly.
$security = $client->getProfile()->getCollector('security');
$this->assertTrue($security->isAuthenticated());
$this->assertEquals(
    'Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\PreAuthenticatedToken',
    $security->getTokenClass()
);
```

The last assertion on the `PreAuthenticatedToken` fails and PHPUnit spits out an error of:

> Failed asserting that Symfony\Component\VarDumper\Cloner\Data Object
>   &00000000299a8bd300000000690a732b matches expected
>   'Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\PreAuthenticatedToken'.

The full output is here: https://gist.github.com/crmpicco/a927716570a4949caafec4ca1361bf63

I can't see anything around the security section in the Symfony upgrade notes that would point to what is causing this error and I must admit i'm a bit stumped with this one now. Do I have some misconfiguration?

Comment: Do you see any other errors or deprecations in your app/logs/test.log?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly the reason, but it seems that `SecurityDataCollector::getTokenClass()` returns a string only when `Symfony\Component\VarDumper\Caster\ClassStub` class doesn't exist (ie. `VarDumper` is not loaded/installed) as you can see [here](https://github.com/symfony/security-bundle/blob/master/DataCollector/SecurityDataCollector.php#L129).

Therefore you should call `$security->getTokenClass()->getValue()` to get string value or better cast it to string to avoid errors when `getTokenClass()` returns already a string:

```
$this->assertEquals(
    'Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\PreAuthenticatedToken',
    (string) $security->getTokenClass()
);
```

Comment: Thanks, however doing that just converts the `getTokenClass` output to `AnonymousToken` when it should be a `PreAuthenticatedToken`.

Comment: Well, this is something I can't really figure out, it's related to the test itself and the system behind it...